# How to select from database in a file?

Tags: postgresql, h2

How to read H2 DB from a file?
I have configured it in IntelliJ as a Normal DB, but I want to Union some of data from DB File with PostgreSQL

[image]

For example PostgreSQL and my H2 DB File have same Tables:

```sql
select * from filename(C:/h2.mv.db) USERS 
union 
select * from USERS
```

Answer (score 1):

dump the table to a delimited text format like TSV and load it into postgresql using postgresql [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html)

or perhaps use a [foreign data wrapper](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers) to wrap the other db driver.
I am not aware of one for H2 DB. They are not always super-difficult to build, using something like [multicorn](https://multicorn.org/).

If you don't need live queries between both databases, and you can manage with an extract and load, it's probably simpler to do that.

Comment: That wont help me, the Data in DB File will be updated daily from another project and should reunion with the other DB. There will be also a cronjob who does the report from united table.

Comment: in which case extract and load into postgresql daily after the update, or implement the suggested SQL/MED approach with foreign data services